# How could I return mat of opencv.js to c++

Tags: c++, opencv, webassembly

Writing a webapp for browser(proof of concept of wasm), want to return the mat captured by the webcam back to the c++ site in order to process the image and display it(ui is written by Qt5).

How could I return the Mat? Solution I found are

1. iterate pixels by img.ucharPtr, copy the pixels value to string and return it to c++. But iterate pixel by js is slow, not an ideal solution.
2. Use imencode to encode the Mat to jpg and return it, problem is when I call imencode, it give me error message "cv.imencode is not a function". I download the opencv.js from [this link, it is official site](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/opencv.js).

   ```
   function captureFrame()
   {
       console.log("capture frame start");
       console.log("cols = ", global_frame.cols, ", rows = ",  global_frame.rows, ", type = ", global_frame.type(), ", steps = ", global_frame.step[0]);
       global_cap.read(global_frame);  // Read a frame from camera
       console.log("convert from rgba 2 rgb");
       cv.cvtColor(global_frame, global_rgb_frame, cv.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

       console.log("convert to byte64 string");
       var base64_frame = cv.imencode(".jpg", global_rgb_frame).toString('base64');
       var length_bytes = lengthBytesUTF8(base64_frame);
       var string_on_wasm_heap = _malloc(length_bytes);
       stringToUTF8(base64_frame, string_on_wasm_heap, length_bytes);

       return string_on_wasm_heap;
   }
   ```

It would be perfect if I could open the webcam and access the frame directly from c++, but haven't found a way to do that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, quite simple.

```
function captureFrame()
{
    console.log("capture frame start");
    console.log("cols = ", global_frame.cols, ", rows = ", global_frame.rows, ", type = ", global_frame.type(), ", steps = ", global_frame.step[0]);
    global_cap.read(global_frame);

    console.log("convert from rgba 2 rgb");
    cv.cvtColor(global_frame, global_rgb_frame, cv.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    HEAPU8.set(global_rgb_frame.data, global_buffer);
    console.log("buffer values = ", buffer[0], ", ", buffer[1], ", ", buffer[2]);
    console.log("global_rgb_frame.data values = ", global_rgb_frame.data[0], ", ", global_rgb_frame.data[1], ", ", global_rgb_frame.data[2]);        

    return global_buffer;    
}
```

global_buffer is a heap I init when I start the camera, in order to reduce the need of memory allocation, I make it as a global variable, this ugly trick is common to see when I need to communicate with different languages.

```
try{
        // Get a permission from user to use a camera.
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
          .then(function(stream) {
              global_camera.srcObject = stream;
              let {width, height} = stream.getTracks()[0].getSettings();
              global_height = height;
              global_width = width;
              console.log("width x height of stream = ", width, "," , height);
              global_frame = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC4);
              global_rgb_frame = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC3);
              global_camera.setAttribute("width", width);
              global_camera.setAttribute("height", height);
              global_buffer = _malloc(global_rgb_frame.rows * global_rgb_frame.cols * 3);

              global_camera.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {                  
                  global_camera.play();
                  //! [Open a camera stream]
                  global_cap = new cv.VideoCapture(global_camera);  //*/
          };
        });        
    }catch(err){
        console.log("err:", err, ", err messages:", err.message);
    }
```

After that, register the function in your cpp file.

```
EM_JS(unsigned char*, capture_frame, (), {
    return captureFrame();
})
```

Convert the buffer to the QImage and draw it on the QLabel

```
    auto *buffer = capture_frame();
    auto const width = get_frame_width(); //access js global variable
    auto const height = get_frame_height(); //access js global variable
    qDebug()<<__func__<<"width x height = "<<width<<", "<<height;
    qDebug()<<__func__<<"buffer values = "<<buffer[0]<<", "<<buffer[1]<<", "<<buffer[2];
    cv::Mat frame(height, width, CV_8UC3, buffer);
    QImage img(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows,
               static_cast<int>(frame.step[0]), QImage::Format_RGB888);
    ui->labelImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img.copy()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, you can use the code below which I found from this [Opencv thread](https://answers.opencv.org/question/5768/how-can-i-get-one-single-frame-from-a-video-file/).

Just take a screen cap of the latest frame from the video capture, and return it as a mat object.

```
VideoCapture cap("video1.mp4"); 

if( !cap.isOpened())
{
     cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
     return -1;
}

double count = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); //get the frame count
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,count-1); //Set index to last frame
namedWindow("Screen Cap", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while(1)
{
    Mat frame;
    bool success = cap.read(frame); 
    if (!success){
      cout << "Cannot read  frame " << endl;
      break;
    }
    imshow("MyVideo", frame);
    if(waitKey(0) == 27) break;
}
```

If you want some further indepth analysis, I found these [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) here.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I meant. I want to return the cv::Mat from javascript back to c++

Comment: @StereoMatching Ah, my apologies, I though you were just asking for the conversion from C++.